# how to count number of rows between a given time interval window

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe which contain 2 column event-time(timestamp) and color(string) i want to count number of rows between each second.

```
  event-time              color
  2019-08-01 00:00:00    orange
  2019-08-01 00:00:20    orange
  2019-08-01 00:00:44    yellow
  2019-08-01 00:01:00    pink
  2019-08-01 00:01:20    pink
  2019-08-01 00:02:00    black
      ....               ...
  2019-08-07 00:01:00    pink
```

and I want like this

```
    event-time            count
    2019-08-01 00:00:00   3
    2019-08-01 00:01:00   2
    2019-08-01 00:02:00   1
         ...              ...
```

I tried with window function but i didn't get the output as i expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `window` function here.

First create the DataFrame, if the `event-time` is in `StringType`, convert it into `TimestampType`.

```
df = df.withColumn('time', F.to_timestamp(df['event-time'], 'yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss'))
df.show()
```

Here's the DataFrame we have:

```
+------------------+------+-------------------+
|        event-time| color|               time|
+------------------+------+-------------------+
|2019-08-0100:00:00|orange|2019-08-01 00:00:00|
|2019-08-0100:00:20|orange|2019-08-01 00:00:20|
|2019-08-0100:00:44|yellow|2019-08-01 00:00:44|
|2019-08-0100:01:00|  pink|2019-08-01 00:01:00|
|2019-08-0100:01:20|  pink|2019-08-01 00:01:20|
|2019-08-0100:02:00| black|2019-08-01 00:02:00|
+------------------+------+-------------------+
```

Next, Group the `event-time` by a `1 minute` window, and use `agg` to `count`:

```
w = df.groupBy(F.window("time", "1 minute")).agg(F.count("event-time").alias("count"))
w.orderBy('window').show()
w.select(w.window.start.cast("string").alias("start"), w.window.end.cast("string").alias("end"), "count").orderBy('start').show()
```

Here's what you get at the end:

```
+--------------------+-----+
|              window|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|[2019-08-01 00:00...|    3|
|[2019-08-01 00:01...|    2|
|[2019-08-01 00:02...|    1|
+--------------------+-----+


+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|              start|                end|count|
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|2019-08-01 00:00:00|2019-08-01 00:01:00|    3|
|2019-08-01 00:01:00|2019-08-01 00:02:00|    2|
|2019-08-01 00:02:00|2019-08-01 00:03:00|    1|
+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
```

You can replace `1 minute` with other time intervals, e.g. 
`1 second`, `1 day 12 hours`, `2 minutes`, etc.

See [the documentation here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.window)

Comment: Thank you..@NeilZ As per your method i tried and it is working fine. But when i tried for 1 hour it showing from last 30 min to current 30 min like 2019-08-01 00:30:00 2019-08-01 01:30:00 but i want like these 2019-08-01 00:00:00 2019-08-01 01:00:00 . In window function there is concept of **slideDuration** is it helpful for these if helpful how to use it?

Comment: @vishwajeetMane I am a bit confused here. Do you have a last row of 2019-08-01 00:30:00 and want to make it 2019-08-01 00:00:00?  It’ll be great if you can post the data from last rows and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a range variable and use it to group and count. Something like the following should help

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

seconds = 1
seconds_window = F.from_unixtime(F.unix_timestamp('event-time')\
       - F.unix_timestamp('event-time') % seconds)
df = df.withColumn('1sec_window', seconds_window)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to group the event-time by minutes, you can try [pyspark.sql.functions.**date_trunc**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_trunc) (*spark 2.3+*)

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import date_trunc, to_timestamp

>>> df.show()                                                                                                                   
+-------------------+------+
|         event-time| color|
+-------------------+------+
|2019-08-01 00:00:00|orange|
|2019-08-01 00:00:20|orange|
|2019-08-01 00:00:44|yellow|
|2019-08-01 00:01:00|  pink|
|2019-08-01 00:01:20|  pink|
|2019-08-01 00:02:00| black|
+-------------------+------+

>>> df.withColumn('event-time', date_trunc('minute', to_timestamp('event-time'))).show()                                    
+-------------------+------+
|         event-time| color|
+-------------------+------+
|2019-08-01 00:00:00|orange|
|2019-08-01 00:00:00|orange|
|2019-08-01 00:00:00|yellow|
|2019-08-01 00:01:00|  pink|
|2019-08-01 00:01:00|  pink|
|2019-08-01 00:02:00| black|
+-------------------+------+
```

Then groupby on the updated `event-time` and count the rows:

```
>>> df.withColumn('event-time', date_trunc('minute', to_timestamp('event-time'))) \
  .groupBy('event-time') \
  .count() \
  .show()     
+-------------------+-----+                                                     
|         event-time|count|
+-------------------+-----+
|2019-08-01 00:01:00|    2|
|2019-08-01 00:00:00|    3|
|2019-08-01 00:02:00|    1|
+-------------------+-----+
```

**Note:** if `event-time` is already a `TimestampType`, then skip the function *to_timestamp()* and use the `event-time` field directly.